# How to draw a circle with given X and Y coordinates as the middle spot of the circle?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, java-2d, paintcomponent

I have developed a telecommunication application for locating signal strengths from the towers. I have used java swing and I'm having a problem when drawing the circle around the given point of the mobile signal transmitter tower location. I have already calculated the X, Y coordinates and also the radius value.

Please find the below code which I've used to draw the circle and it is having issues.

```
JPanel panelBgImg = new JPanel() {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawOval(X, Y, r, r);
    }
}
```

The issue is, it creates the circle but it didn't take the X and Y coordinates as the center point. It took the X and Y coordinates as the top left point of the circle.

Could anyone please help me to draw the circle by having the given X and Y coordinates as the center point of the circle.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `fillOval` fits an oval inside a rectangle, `with width=r, height = r` you get a circle.
If you want `fillOval(x,y,r,r)` to draw a circle with the center at (x,y) you will have to displace the rectangle by half its width and half its height.

```
public void drawCenteredCircle(Graphics2D g, int x, int y, int r) {
  x = x-(r/2);
  y = y-(r/2);
  g.fillOval(x,y,r,r);
}
```

This will draw a circle with center at `x,y`

Comment: +1 for noticing the OP was using `r` (radius) as a pseudo `d` (diameter).  The parameters are labelled `w` and `h` in the docs.

Comment: This answer is wrong. It does paint an oval at (x,y) as center, but the radius is wrong. Please use Justin's answer!

Answer (score 14):

So we are all doing the same home work?

Strange how the most up-voted answer is wrong. Remember, draw/fillOval take height and width as parameters, not the radius. So to correctly draw and center a circle with user-provided x, y, and radius values you would do something like this:

```
public static void drawCircle(Graphics g, int x, int y, int radius) {

  int diameter = radius * 2;

  //shift x and y by the radius of the circle in order to correctly center it
  g.fillOval(x - radius, y - radius, diameter, diameter); 

}
```

Comment: ' *Strange how the most up-voted answer is wrong* '. It is not wrong, he is just using the letter *r* as diameter which is the height and width. That's how the OP is naming his variable.

Answer (score 6):

Replace your draw line with

```
g.drawOval(X - r, Y - r, r, r)
```

This should make the top-left of your circle the right place to make the center be `(X,Y)`,
at least as long as the point `(X - r,Y - r)` has both components in range.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it works even if the top-left corner is out of range

Comment: I've never tried drawing things offscreen, so I'll take your word for that. Certainly, however, it does work if the corner is in range.

Comment: I agree with @Cruncher

Answer (score 3):

```
drawCircle(int X, int Y, int Radius, ColorFill, Graphics gObj)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).  

When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Answer (score 2):

```
JPanel pnlCircle = new JPanel() {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            int X=100;
            int Y=100;
            int d=200;
            g.drawOval(X, Y, d, d);
        }
};
```

you can change X,Y coordinates and radius what you want.

Answer (score 1):

both answers are is incorrect. it should read:

```
x-=r;
y-=r;


drawOval(x,y,r*2,r*2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Graphiic
{   
    public Graphics GClass;
    public Graphics2D G2D;
    public  void Draw_Circle(JFrame jf,int radius , int  xLocation, int yLocation)
    {
        GClass = jf.getGraphics();
        GClass.setPaintMode();
        GClass.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        GClass.fillArc(xLocation, yLocation, radius, radius, 0, 360);
        GClass.drawLine(100, 100, 200, 200);    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This draws an arc with the center in the specified rectangle. You can draw, half-circles, quarter-circles, etc.

```
g.drawArc(x - r, y - r, r * 2, r * 2, 0, 360)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me:

```
g.drawOval((getWidth()-200)/2,(getHeight()-200)/2, 200, 200);
```